# Есть реализация функции zip и enumerate. Как можно упростить код?

Tags: python

```
def zi(*iterables):
    length = min(map(len, iterables))
    result = []
    for index in range(length):
        new_item = tuple(map(lambda item: item[index], iterables))
        result.append(new_item)
    return result

def enumerat(iterable, start=0):
    result = []
    for index in range(len(iterable)):
        new_item = (index + start, iterable[index])
        result.append(new_item)
    return result
```

Comment: `def zi(*iterables): return zip(iterables)`

Comment: Ни `zip`, ни `enumerate` не должны измерять длину `iterable`. Её может просто не быть.

Comment: Оба не могут накапливать результат в списке. Это генераторы, которые возвращают значения как только те будут доступны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

основной вопрос - "ЗАЧЕМ" :)

Ну тем не менее можно упросить код так:

```
def zi(*iterables):
    return [tuple(map(lambda item: item[index], iterables)) for index in range(min(map(len, iterables)))]
```

и

```
def enumerat(iterable, start=0):
    return [(index + start, iterable[index]) for index in range(len(iterable))]
```

P.S.

используя функцию `zip` можно сильно сократить функцию `enumerat`:

```
def enumerat(iterable, start=0):
    return zip(range(start, start + len(iterable)), iterable)
```

Comment: `return [...]` -> `return (...)` в обеих функциях. Это должны быть генераторы.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем говорить об упрощении надо обсудить функциональность. Выдержит ли `enumerat` такое применение?

```
import sys


for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, start=1):
    print(f'{i}: {repr(line)}')
```

> ```
> $ python zip-sample.py < zip-sample.py 
> 1: 'import sys\n'
> 2: '\n'
> 3: '\n'
> 4: 'for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, start=1):\n'
> 5: "    print(f'{i}: {repr(line)}')\n"
> ```

`sys.stdin` поддерживает перечисление строк, но функция `len` к нему не применима (длина входного потока не известна) и обращаться по индексу тоже нельзя. Ваш вариант работает только со списками и кортежами (`tuple`) но не с любыми `iterable`. В документации приводится что-то вроде референсной реализации [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def enumerate_(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

Этот вариант проще и работает с любым `iterable`.

С `zip` ситуация ещё хуже. Даже в документации примера нет.

```
def zip_(*iterables):

    class ZipExit(Exception):
        pass

    def next_(it):
        try:
            return next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise ZipExit

    # iterators = tuple(map(iter, iterables))
    iterators = tuple(iter(it) for it in iterables)
    try:
        while True:
            # yield tuple(map(next_, iterators))
            yield tuple(next_(it) for it in iterators)
    except ZipExit:
        pass
```

Тут требуются объяснения. Самый общий протокол для `iterable` выглядит так:

> ```
> iterator = iter(interable) # создаём итератор
> v0 = next(iterator)        # извлекаем значения
> v1 = next(iterator)
> ...
> vn = next(iterator)
> next(iterator)             # когда данные закончились
>                            # next бросает исключение StopIteration
> ```

Так как мы хотим обработать любые последовательности (`iterable`), следует использовать этот протокол.

Исключение `ZipExit` нужно так как это единственный способ сообщить об ошибке (кончились данные) при вычислении аргумента вызова `tuple`. Хочется бросать и ловить `StopIteration` но язык это явно запрещает. А любое другое стандартное исключение нельзя использовать так как такое же исключение можно получить при вызове `next(it)`, который может привести к исполнению кода на Python с произвольной логикой внутри. Поэтому уникальный тип исключения.

Вызовы `map` я поместил в комментарии на случай если вы хотите решение с минимумом обращений к глобальным функциям Python.

Если использовать `map` можно, то есть вариант проще:

```
def zip_(*iterables):
    iterators = tuple(map(iter, iterables))
    while True:
        t = tuple(map(next, iterators))
        if len(t) != len(iterators):
            break
        yield t
```

Тут есть одно тонкое место: вызов `next` рано или поздно должен привести к выбрасыванию `StopIteration` и код завершится с ошибкой - из генераторов, а `zip_` - генератор, бросать `StopIteration` нельзя. И однако этот код работает благодаря тому что вызов `next` делается в теле `map`, который перехватывает `StopIteration` (и только его) и возвращает не полный кортеж. Что проверяется и у нас есть шанс завершить `zip_` нормально.

Хотя этот код выглядит просто, устроен он сложно. Я бы не рекомендовал это в качестве нормальной практики.